# C# For loop and arrays

Tags: c#

I need help with this loop and displaying the array correctly into a label. Here is  the Code

```
private void ErrorEquipment()
{
    string[] Equips = { "Projector", "Computer", "Network", "Webcam" };

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        if (venue.Equipment[i] == true)
        {
            lblEquipment.Text = ("Room Has " + Equips[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to check if the venue has the equipment and if so it, display what equipment the venue has in a label. Currently it checks that but if a venue has more than one equipment available and it overwrites the first equipment that was put in the label.

Comment: Do you want to concat all equipments in the same label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you redefine your variable `lblEquipment.Text` in every iteration. Try this instead:

```
    lblEquipment.Text = "Room Has ";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        if (venue.Equipment[i] == true)
        {
            lblEquipment.Text += Equips[i] + " ";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it something like this.

```
lblEquipment.Text = "Room Has ";
for (int counter = 0; counter <= 3; counter++)
{
    if (venue.Equipment[counter] == true)
        lblEquipment.Text += Equips[counter] + " ";
}
```

But this is too inefficient because when you concatenate strings, it always creates a `new instance of string` because `string` is **immutable**, and since you're in a for loop, the instance you're creating is being wasted.

To better implement this, you must create a `StringBuilder` object and then `ToString` it after the loop. Something like this.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("Room Has ");
for (int counter = 0; counter <= 3; counter++)
{
    if (venue.Equipment[counter] == true)
        builder.Append(Equips[counter] + " ");
}
lblEquipment.Text = builder.ToString();
```

More info about `Immutable` objects here: [C# Tips & Tricks: Immutable Types](http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/CSharp/Immutables.html)

Answer (score 1):

you are replacing each time Label `lblEquipment` value.

you need to do [String Concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx://) instead of just assigning new value.

Use a variable to Store result and then display:

```
 string rooms ="Room Has ";
 for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) 
{ 
  if (venue.Equipment[i] == true) 
     rooms += ","+Equips[i]; // concatenating with previous value
}
lblEquipment.Text = rooms;
```

A linq inspired solution would be:

```
var result = venue.Equipment.Select((v, index) => new { v, index })
                            .Where(pair => pair.v == true && pair.index <=3)
                            .Select(pair => Equips[pair.index]);

lblEquipment.Text = "Room Has "+ string.Join(",",result);
```